# Multiple IF Statement VBA Date Range - syntax error

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, vba

I have VBA to run a query that connects to a form with a date range. I'm trying to write an IF statement that incorporates two text boxes for Start Date and End Date. I'm getting a syntax error on my below IF statement can you help? :

```
Option Compare Database
Function ImportPurchases()

Dim qdfPassThrough As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyDB As Database
Dim strConnect As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Set qdfPassThrough = db.QueryDefs("Netezza_abc_purch_track")

If Not IsNull((Forms![DateRange].StartDate)) And Not IsNull((Forms![DateRange].EndDate)) Then
    strSQL = "SELECT A.STORE_NBR,A.ITEM_NBR, A.NDC_NBR, C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NBR, C.INV_CUST_NAME ,C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME, Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)as Allocated_Qty, Sum(INV_LINE_AMT) as Extended_Cost FROM FCT_DLY_INVOICE_DETAIL A, FCT_DLY_INVOICE_HEADER B, DIM_INVOICE_CUSTOMER C WHERE A.INV_HDR_SK = B.INV_HDR_SK AND B.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = C.DIM_INV_CUST_SK AND A.STORE_NBR=B.STORE_NBR AND A.INV_DT BETWEEN (" & Forms![DateRange].StartDate & ")and (" & Forms![DateRange].EndDate & ")AND A.SUPPLIER_NBR NOT IN ('50000181', '20000775', '50000809', '50000950') AND A.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC' AND C.INV_CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%340B%' AND C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME NOT LIKE '%340B%' Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6"
Else
    strSQL = "ERROR"
End If
qdfPassThrough.SQL = strSQL
strConnect = "ODBC;DSN=NZSQL;Database=PRD_EDW_RXPURCHASING_DB;Server"
qdfPassThrough.Connect = strConnect
qdfPassThrough.Close


DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

Comment: This may be yet another inexperienced comment, but where do you declare `db`? I only see `MyDB`.

Comment: @ChristopherD is correct.   Thus the need for `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

Option Explicit
Private Sub Command9_Click()
'JB Function ImportPurchases() updated this to private sub, Function is for modules, and updated the name to reflect the button name plus _click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim qdf As QueryDef

```
Dim qdfPassThrough As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyDB As Database
Dim strConnect As String

'JB Dim SQLstr As String, you had this reversed in the sql :)

Dim strSQL As String
Dim DateStart As Date
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim DateStart_string As String
Dim DateEnd_string As String



    'Set db and querydef variables
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Netezza_abc_purch_track")

'Initialize variables with values from the form
      DateStart = Forms!DateRange!DateStart.Value
    DateStart_string = Format(DateStart, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    DateEnd = Forms!DateRange!DateEnd.Value
    DateEnd_string = Format(DateEnd, "yyyy-mm-dd")



    strSQL = "SELECT A.STORE_NBR,A.ITEM_NBR, A.NDC_NBR, C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NBR, C.INV_CUST_NAME ,C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME, Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)as Allocated_Qty, Sum(INV_LINE_AMT) as Extended_Cost " & _
    "FROM FCT_DLY_INVOICE_DETAIL A, FCT_DLY_INVOICE_HEADER B, DIM_INVOICE_CUSTOMER C WHERE A.INV_HDR_SK = B.INV_HDR_SK AND B.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = C.DIM_INV_CUST_SK AND A.STORE_NBR=B.STORE_NBR " & _
    "AND A.INV_DT BETWEEN ('" & DateStart_string & "') and ('" & DateEnd_string & "')  AND A.SUPPLIER_NBR NOT IN ('50000181', '20000775', '50000809', '50000950') " & _
    "AND A.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC' AND C.INV_CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%340B%' AND C.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME NOT LIKE '%340B%' Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6"

   qdf.SQL = strSQL

 Set db = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    'DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro1"

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Netezza_abc_purch_track"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The `If` keyword cannot be used twice in the same statement. Remove the second one.

```
If Not IsNull(...) And Not IsNull(...) Then
    strSQL = ...
Else
    strSQL = ...
End If
```

(What is the precise error message?)

(I wonder why your VBA has missing spaces?  The editor cleans all that up, or throws dialog boxes.  Just curious on my part, I guess.)

---

Your version of the code as of 9:00 AM has this comparison clause:

```
isnull  >= (Forms![DateRange].StartDate)
```

I think you want something like this:

```
IsNull((Forms![DateRange].StartDate))
```

As a general advice, I suggest you make some minimal working bits of code using a testing or trial mindset, learn the building blocks, and then work up to your actual need.

### IMPORTANT

Type `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.  Then use `Debug > Compile Database`.  This will reveal critical errors in your code and probably lead to you resolving your syntax error.

Comment: I removed the IF and it deleted my second statement, then the error is "application defined or object defined error"...how do i clean this up to include a date range in this statement because I have two text boxes with dates in them....

Comment: Can you update your post with the latest code?  In the code above you are still missing spaces before `and` and before `then`.

Comment: sorry, just read your example, let me try that and update my code.

Comment: Please use `debug.print`as Hans suggested, then you find the typos in the sql string (e.g. there is a space missing in `Forms![DateRange].StartDate & ")and` it should be `Forms![DateRange].StartDate & ") and`). Use `debug.print` on `Forms![DateRange].StartDate`  and `EndDate` . Put them in front of the sql string. **AND PLEASE** add linebreaks to your sql string, it not readable easy formated like that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you (also) need to format proper string expressions for your dates:

```
... (A.INV_DT Between '" & Format(Forms![DateRange]!StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "' And '" & Format(Forms![DateRange]!EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "') And A.SUPPLIER_NBR ...
```